# Using range and length function together in python

Tags: python-3.x, range

Just want to understand the logic of using - range(len()) for the purpose of indexing

for eg. i have  `mylist=[1,2,3,4,5]`

so here -> `len(mylist)` would be `5`

and `range(len(mylist))` would be `(0,5)`

however the computer starts reading from `0` as position : making `mylist 0 to 4`
where `mylist[4]= 5`
so here do we use `range(len(mylist)-1` to set the range correctly for the purpose of indexing ?
apologies if i am not clear (beginner)
Thanks.

Comment: You can turn any iterable into a list with `list(it)`. `list(range(len(mylist)))` might be illuminating.

Comment: If you want to know what values you get by making a certain call to `range`, why not **try it**? Write the loop and `print` the values that are `in` the range, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Range

Let's look at just `range`.

Check out what the help section says. You can get to help from your terminal by typing `python3` and then typing `help(range)`. To get out of the help, press `q`. To get out of the terminal, type `quit()`.

```
% python3
Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec 28 2020, 11:25:16) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help(range)
```

Here's the relevant help area:

```
Help on class range in module builtins:

class range(object)
 |  range(stop) -> range object
 |  range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
 |  
 |  Return an object that produces a sequence of integers from start (inclusive)
 |  to stop (exclusive) by step.  range(i, j) produces i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1.
 |  start defaults to 0, and stop is omitted!  range(4) produces 0, 1, 2, 3.
 |  These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
 |  When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
```

If you were to type:

```
for item in range(5):
    print(item)
```

You will get 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Range takes start, stop and step as an argument. Start, if not provided, is zero. Zero is inclusive. We provided stop of 5. But note that 5 is exclusive. That means, range will print from 0 and stop before 5.

## List

Your list `mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` has 5 items. To access the first item, you'd write `mylist[0]`. To get to the last item, you'd write `mylist[4]`.

## Combine range and list

Instead of typing `range(5)`, you can as well type `range(len(mylist))`, len(mylist) is 5.

Let's say you typed this code in test.py

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]

for index in range(5):
    print(f'Range = {index} and mylist item is {mylist[index]}')
```

If you run it, this is what you'll see:

```
python3 test.py
Range = 0 and mylist item is 1
Range = 1 and mylist item is 2
Range = 2 and mylist item is 3
Range = 3 and mylist item is 4
Range = 4 and mylist item is 5
```

Notice how we went from mylist[0] through mylist[4] using range(5), wherein range(5) gave us numbers from 0 to 4.

Feel free to ask follow-up questions in comments.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. A following question would be if i code- 'range(len(mylist)-1)', would this give me access to only 4 items in the list ?

Comment: @KevinJohn Yes, `range(len(mylist) - 1)` will result in `range(4)` and that means, 0, 1, 2 and 3. As you said, that just corresponds to the first 4 items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the length of the list is always one greater than it's last index.  In your exmaple, the length of the list is 5, whereas the final index is 4. So when you say range(len(my_list)), the range that stops one short compensates for the len that is one too long.  It all works out nicely so that you iterate through all items of the list by range(len(my_list)).